# How to give different text shadow levels for different browsers

Tags: html, css

When I use the text shadow css, mozilla and chrome are showing different smudging levels.

```
 #dfg{  
 color: #fff; 
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
 }
```

In mozilla I'm getting a more smudged look which i don't want. I've tried

```
-moz-text-shadow : 0px 0px 1px white;
```

but it doesn't help. Is there a method in css to give browser specific text shadow values or should i go for a javascript to identify the browser and then select a shadow level.? Please help.

chrome version

[image: Chrome version]

mozilla version

[image: mozilla version]

Answer (score -1):

Personally I think a Javascript based method would work best, all modren browsers support the standard CSS shadow function, I think you were thinking of -moz-window-shadow which is a OSX feature.

also look into the blur property of text-shadow, perhaps explicitly defining it?